# In PHP, replace a number with "string" depending on ranges?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I need a php function to convert some numbers into a "string" (using quotation marks because of not sure if it's the proper name) according to some ranges.

**Problem**

- In my web, I have different numbers (in different fields that may change) which I want to modify
- I need a function which change the numbers into a "string" depending on a range

**Information**

*Numbers*

- Numbers can be from 0 to 5000

*My ranges*

- From 0 to 150
- From 151 to 300
- From 301 to 500
- Up to 501

*Range - string relation*

- From 0 to 150 --> "Less than 150 m2"
- From 151 to 300 --> "150 - 300 m2"
- From 301 to 500 --> "300 - 500 m2"
- Up to 501 --> "Up to 500 m2"

**Examples**

- Number: 180 -- (this number is <300 and > 151) --> Output: "150 - 300 m2"
- Number: 524 -- (this number is > 501) --> Output: "Up to 500 m2"

**What I've achieved**
I'm looking for a better way to do this. Any documentation is also welcomed.

```
<?php
function my_map_field($data) {
    $map = array(
        '0' => 'Less than 150 m2',
        '1' => 'Less than 150 m2',
        '2' => 'Less than 150 m2',
        '3' => 'Less than 150 m2',
        '4' => 'Less than 150 m2', /*Imagine all the numbers*/
        '151' => '150 - 300 m2',  /*Imagine all the numbers*/
        '301' => '300 - 500 m2',  /*Imagine all the numbers*/
    );

    return isset( $map[$data] ) ? $map[$data] : $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Let us see your code, so that we can give you some hints. Stack Overflow is not a coding service.

Comment: What have you managed so far? Do you have any code at all?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm a rookie, so all I've achieve is something like this:

<?php
function my_map_field($data) {
 $map = array(
  '0' => 'Less than 150 m2',
  '1' => 'Less than 150 m2',
  '2' => 'Less than 150 m2',
  '3' => 'Less than 150 m2',
  '4' => 'Less than 150 m2', /*Imagine all the numbers*/
  '151' => '150 - 300 m2',  /*Imagine all the numbers*/
  '301' => '300 - 500 m2',  /*Imagine all the numbers*/
 );

 return isset( $map[$data] ) ? $map[$data] : $data;
}
?>

Comment: @irek19 see my answer below. You have some conflicts in your question so I did the best I could. You wrote number can be between 0 and 5000 and your example is 5240. I just wrote the code, didn't make it a function. It was enough work to do that on the phone, but do you want me to change it to a function?

Comment: @Andreas I corrected the number (my fault). I'm using your code to read some documentation and understand how it works and change it into a function. Would be great if you could change it, but if not, any documentation to learn how to do it by myself would be also ok.

Comment: @irek19 try the updated code. Have not tested it as I'm using my phone.

Comment: I just looked at your code again. Are you serious that you want an array with 5000 items but 4996 of them are "duplicates"?

Comment: I was the only way I knew, this is because I look for help here. Google searches was dissapointed and I'm starting with this, so I haven't many resources... W3schools and php.net are ok when you know what are looking for, but not useful if you have no idea about what you want to look for.

Comment: Is the input always a number and only a number? In that case the code can be simplified.

Comment: Yes, always and only numbers (no commas, no full stops).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the numbers with regex then str_replace them.
Regex pattern \d+ finds numbers.

```
function replace_numbers($str) {

 Preg_match_all("/(\d+)/", $str, $arr);
 //Var_dump($arr);
 For ($i=0; $i<count($arr[0]);$i++){
     If($arr[0][$i]>=0 && $arr[0][$i]<=150) $str = str_replace($arr[0][$i], "less than 150 m2", $str);
     If($arr[0][$i]>=151 && $arr[0][$i]<=300) $str = str_replace($arr[0][$i], "151 - 300 m2", $str);
     If($arr[0][$i]>=301 && $arr[0][$i]<=500) $str = str_replace($arr[0][$i], "301 - 500 m2", $str);
     If($arr[0][$i]>=501 && $arr[0][$i]<=5000) $str = str_replace($arr[0][$i], "up to 500 m2", $str);

 }

Return $str;
}

$str ="Number: 180, Number: 524";  // the string that needs attention
$newstr = replace_numbers($str); // newstr is the old string but with replaced numbers
```

I have not included anything that takes care of numbers above 5000.
Also since you have not given much examples it will not work strings like "I'm 30 years old and my house is 400 m2" because it will replace 30 also.